# Problema con .toggle al usar .load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Muy buenas. Tengo una tabla en html que muestra diferentes datos. Cada fila de la celda se puede pinchar y gracias a .toggle se despliegan más datos. Ahora le he implementado un script para que la tabla se vaya refrescando automáticamente y el script de .toggle ha dejado de funcionar. ¿Alguien me puede decir como arreglarlo? Aquí dejo el script de toggle y el de actualizar automáticamente:

Script de toggle para poder ver información extra al pinchar en la fila de la tabla (".datatable tr")

```
<script>
    //ocultar-mostrar información
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datatable tr").click(function(){
            $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-graf')).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Script que actualiza automáticamente la tabla

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#seccionRecargar").load(window.location.href + " #seccionRecargar" );
        }, 20000); //se refresca cada 20 segundos 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estas implementando una solución que ya no se ve como buena práctica puede ser poco funcional. Si lo único que quieres es recargar la tabla, creo que deberías utilizar AJAX para hacerlo, de hecho la propia documentación de [DataTables tiene asincronía integrada](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

También hay llamados deprecados en Jquery y buenas prácticas que tienes que mejorar, tu código debería lucir de esta forma

```
<script>
     // Lo mismo que document.ready
    $( () => {

        $( document ).on( 'click', '.datatable tr', function() {
            // Obtenemos el valor del atributo, también puedes usar $( this ).data('graf');
            const attr = $( this ).attr( 'data-graf' );
            // Acostubra a hacer backticks para concatenar
            $( `.cat${ attr }` ).toggle();
        });

        // Así instanciamos y le decimos que esta tabla será una data table
        const table = $( '.datatable' ).DataTable({
            ajax: 'path_to_endpoint.php'
        });

        // Así podemos recargarla, después del tiempo que quieras
        setInterval( () => table.ajax.reload(), 20000 );

    });


</script>
```

Te dejo la documentación de [datatable.ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) Para que le eches un lente. La forma en la que estas intentando recargar la información te puede causar muchos problemas.

Dale la bienvenida a la asincronía a tu código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a probar a ver si me funciona!